# How to prevent pop up PDF file automatically after downloading it?

Tags: pdf

I use lenovo phone where I faced this problem but I got no solution to fix the problem.

After download of any PDF file it pops up automatically and automatically it opens . This problem is really irritating when I download more than 10 PDF file together . After downloading one file it pops up then I need to close it then return to my download page and download another file it really takes lot of time. Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long press on the download link, and press on *open in new tab* this will download the file in the background instead of opening it right away. You will then be able to access the file by going to *downloads* in chrome or using a file manager.

(Tested on Moto x4 using chrome. Can't vouch for other devices)